# Not able to install go 1.13 in go env. goenv install 1.13.6 fails with - go-build: definition not found: 1.13.6

Tags: go, virtualenv, development-environment

I am trying to install different Go versions for various projects
1. goenv install 1.11.4 was successful
2. go env install 1.13.6 failed with error - go-build: definition not found: 1.13.6

also when i checked available versions for goenv using
goenv install --list
The last one I got is 
  .......
  .......
  1.10.3
  1.10.4
  1.10.5
  1.10.6
  1.10.7
  1.11.0
  1.11beta2
  1.11beta3
  1.11rc1
  1.11rc2
  1.11.1
  1.11.2
  1.11.3
  1.11.4
  1.12beta1

Go is available till 1.14 now
Why all the versions of Go are not available to install in goenv

Comment: You should ask the author of goenv. Note that there is no real reason not to use Go 1.14. You gain nothing by using Go 1.11.x

Answer (score 7):

Try uninstalling `goenv` and then reinstalling it with `--HEAD`. For OSX, it would look like:

```
brew uninstall goenv
brew install --HEAD goenv
```

If that doesn't work, try running the same set of commands once more. Since the new version is still in beta, `goenv` uses the previous version (without 1.14.x) as its default.